# How to switch product colours in a webshop on click?

Tags: javascript, html

i need to make a webshop for school. I have a image product with buttons (which are colours) under it. onclick i want to display another image with a different color. the buttons dont do anything even if I link it to images, can anyone help me?

this is the code what i have:

```js
function change() {
  clothing.src = "";
}

function change2() {
  clothing.src = "#";
}

function change3() {
  clothing.src = "#";
}
```

```html
<div id="clothes">
  <img src="#" id="clothing">
  <button onclick="change()">Click here</button>
  <button onclick="change2()"> Click here</button>
  <button onclick="change3()"> Click here</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the problem or question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions in your question are not setting the image src to image files of a said color.

Suppose you have images `red.jpg`, `green.jpg`, and `blue.jpg` putting in the same folder with the html file. You can change the functions to be:

```js
let clothing = document.querySelector('#clothes img#clothing')
function change() {
  clothing.src = "red.jpg";
}

function change2() {
  clothing.src = "green.jpg";
}

function change3() {
  clothing.src = "blue.jpg";
}
```

```html
<div id="clothes">
  <img src="#" id="clothing">
  <button onclick="change()">Click here</button>
  <button onclick="change2()"> Click here</button>
  <button onclick="change3()"> Click here</button>
</div>
```

You can access the element by id directly.
However, it is better to explicitly reference the image element using `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()` to avoid ambigure case